# Podman machine provider: how do I avoid relying on Qemu VM on linux?

Tags: installation, podman

### straight to the point:

Running on ubuntu 20.04, Podman 4.9.0, running anything that `mmap` to a file mounted on the host filesystem fails. I found it is mostly similar to [this issue](https://github.com/containers/podman/issues/20055) and [this other issue](https://github.com/containers/podman/issues/19639), but it doesn't make sense because I'm on linux right?

### How I installed Podman:

Since the podman version available for ubuntu 20.04 is ancient (3.4), and I can't be bothered to install 10Gb+ for a go toolchain and all dependencies, I downloaded the [binaries available here](https://github.com/containers/podman/releases), as well as `gvproxy`:

```
$ gvproxy --version
gvproxy version 012bc90
```

After this, I ran `podman machine init` and `podman machine start`, this is the result of running `podman info`:

```
host:
  arch: amd64
  buildahVersion: 1.33.2
  cgroupControllers:
  - cpu
  - io
  - memory
  - pids
  cgroupManager: systemd
  cgroupVersion: v2
  conmon:
    package: conmon-2.1.8-2.fc39.x86_64
    path: /usr/bin/conmon
    version: 'conmon version 2.1.8, commit: '
  cpuUtilization:
    idlePercent: 99.14
    systemPercent: 0.54
    userPercent: 0.32
  cpus: 4
  databaseBackend: sqlite
  distribution:
    distribution: fedora
    variant: coreos
    version: "39"
  eventLogger: journald
  freeLocks: 2043
  hostname: localhost.localdomain
  idMappings:
    gidmap:
    - container_id: 0
      host_id: 1000
      size: 1
    - container_id: 1
      host_id: 100000
      size: 1000000
    uidmap:
    - container_id: 0
      host_id: 1000
      size: 1
    - container_id: 1
      host_id: 100000
      size: 1000000
  kernel: 6.6.9-200.fc39.x86_64
  linkmode: dynamic
  logDriver: journald
  memFree: 1678553088
  memTotal: 2059902976
  networkBackend: netavark
  networkBackendInfo:
    backend: netavark
    dns:
      package: aardvark-dns-1.9.0-1.fc39.x86_64
      path: /usr/libexec/podman/aardvark-dns
      version: aardvark-dns 1.9.0
    package: netavark-1.9.0-1.fc39.x86_64
    path: /usr/libexec/podman/netavark
    version: netavark 1.9.0
  ociRuntime:
    name: crun
    package: crun-1.12-1.fc39.x86_64
    path: /usr/bin/crun
    version: |-
      crun version 1.12
      commit: ce429cb2e277d001c2179df1ac66a470f00802ae
      rundir: /run/user/1000/crun
      spec: 1.0.0
      +SYSTEMD +SELINUX +APPARMOR +CAP +SECCOMP +EBPF +CRIU +LIBKRUN +WASM:wasmedge +YAJL
  os: linux
  pasta:
    executable: /usr/bin/pasta
    package: passt-0^20231204.gb86afe3-1.fc39.x86_64
    version: |
      pasta 0^20231204.gb86afe3-1.fc39.x86_64
      Copyright Red Hat
      GNU General Public License, version 2 or later
        <https://www.gnu.org/licenses/old-licenses/gpl-2.0.html>
      This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
      There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
  remoteSocket:
    exists: true
    path: /run/user/1000/podman/podman.sock
  security:
    apparmorEnabled: false
    capabilities: CAP_CHOWN,CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE,CAP_FOWNER,CAP_FSETID,CAP_KILL,CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE,CAP_SETFCAP,CAP_SETGID,CAP_SETPCAP,CAP_SETUID,CAP_SYS_CHROOT
    rootless: true
    seccompEnabled: true
    seccompProfilePath: /usr/share/containers/seccomp.json
    selinuxEnabled: true
  serviceIsRemote: true
  slirp4netns:
    executable: /usr/bin/slirp4netns
    package: slirp4netns-1.2.2-1.fc39.x86_64
    version: |-
      slirp4netns version 1.2.2
      commit: 0ee2d87523e906518d34a6b423271e4826f71faf
      libslirp: 4.7.0
      SLIRP_CONFIG_VERSION_MAX: 4
      libseccomp: 2.5.3
  swapFree: 0
  swapTotal: 0
  uptime: 0h 5m 0.00s
  variant: ""
plugins:
  authorization: null
  log:
  - k8s-file
  - none
  - passthrough
  - journald
  network:
  - bridge
  - macvlan
  - ipvlan
  volume:
  - local
registries:
  search:
  - docker.io
store:
  configFile: /var/home/core/.config/containers/storage.conf
  containerStore:
    number: 5
    paused: 0
    running: 0
    stopped: 5
  graphDriverName: overlay
  graphOptions: {}
  graphRoot: /var/home/core/.local/share/containers/storage
  graphRootAllocated: 106769133568
  graphRootUsed: 4378746880
  graphStatus:
    Backing Filesystem: xfs
    Native Overlay Diff: "true"
    Supports d_type: "true"
    Supports shifting: "false"
    Supports volatile: "true"
    Using metacopy: "false"
  imageCopyTmpDir: /var/tmp
  imageStore:
    number: 52
  runRoot: /run/user/1000/containers
  transientStore: false
  volumePath: /var/home/core/.local/share/containers/storage/volumes
version:
  APIVersion: 4.8.3
  Built: 1704291100
  BuiltTime: Wed Jan  3 09:11:40 2024
  GitCommit: ""
  GoVersion: go1.21.5
  Os: linux
  OsArch: linux/amd64
  Version: 4.8.3
```

I was under the impression that you didn't need a Qemu machine under linux, but if I do `podman machine stop` and then run again any podman command I get:

```
$ podman machine stop
Waiting for VM to exit...
Machine "podman-machine-default" stopped successfully

$ podman info
OS: linux/amd64
provider: qemu
version: 4.9.0

Cannot connect to Podman. Please verify your connection to the Linux system using `podman system connection list`, or try `podman machine init` and `podman machine start` to manage a new Linux VM
Error: unable to connect to Podman socket: failed to connect: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:41191: connect: connection refused
```

It seems there should be something missing in my installation, and I shouldn't have to use a Qemu VM, I would be greatly appreciative of any help or suggestions that doesn't boil down to "build it from sources"

Comment: The `podman machine` command is all about managing a VM. If you want to run containers directly on your actual host then you will need either the old packaged version, a more up-to-date direct installation or a way to run this download outside of the machine setup.